# How can I unwrap each face separately so it takes up the whole picture?

Tags: uv

I want to unwrap each face of my model so that it takes up the whole picture, instead of this:

[image]

I want all of them to look like this:

[image]

I don't want to do it manually. Can anyone help?

Comment: Try to unwrap using U > Reset

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Press <kbd>U</kbd>> *Reset* to unwrap each face so that it takes up the whole image space.